# Ansible interactively respond to non preset remote shell output

Tags: shell, ansible, prompt

I have tried the "expect" and many iterations of the shell / command modules but neither offers what I (and I imagine others) want to do in this case.  Reaching out to the wider group in hopes there is a solution I haven't found yet.

Our software has a shell command that prints out a list of files that it will modify and prompts the user to continue with a standard [y/n] prompt.  Similar to what YUM would do if you were upgrading software, it spits out a bunch of output and waits for user input.

```
The following changes need to be made:

    Create /home/XYZ-file
    Enable and start the ABC service
    Enable and start the DEF service

Allow? [y/N] n
```

SOMETIMES, depending on the files that it lists, we DON'T want to continue... Sometimes, we DO.  so I want to be able to prompt my ansible user and give them the choice based on the list.  I know it's annoying human intervention and not in the spirit of automation, but for this one step we're willing to forego things and have a human actually look at these files and make the decision.

Currently "expect" only matches preset output with preset user responses.  I don't want to do this since I don't know what files will be presented to the user, so I can't use anything preset.

What I would like is to display all the output of the shell command and prompt the ansible user to decide, based on the output.

simple task to issue the command and register the output:

```
- name: Issue XYZ command
  shell: xyz
  register: xyz_output
- debug: var=xyz_output.stdout
```

The problem is that the shell command hangs in this case because ansible isn't able to:

- display the output
  &
- prompt the ansible user to continue or not

Comment: Does the underlying software tolerate running more than once? I ask because if so, you can run it the first time giving `n` answers to every prompt, then you'll have the questions that are going to be asked again next time because they were all `n`-ed the first time (leaving the system in the same state it started in, so long as "n" takes "no" action)

Answer (score 0):

a sample yaml that you can take for reference, and improve as per your requirement.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: print
      shell: cat inventory
      register: fileout

    - debug: var=fileout.stdout

    - name: pause
      pause: prompt='Confirm action by giving - yes/no:'
      register: pause

    - name: Ansible create file.
      file:
         path: "/home/ansible/vops.txt"
         state: touch
         mode: 0777
      when: pause.user_input == 'yes'

    - name: Ansible start service
      service:
         name: httpd
         state: started
      when: pause.user_input == 'yes'
```

i have used '[pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/pause_module.html?highlight=pause)' module to pause the play and prompt for input, and used '[when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html?highlight=when#the-when-statement)' condition to compare the input result and procceed for action.